# Difference in calculating continuity and uniform continuity

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

I've done some exercises on continuity using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition. Now going through my script I saw that there is a stricter version of continuity called uniform continuity. After watching some videos I think I understand the difference and the importance of the quantifiers and their order.
I've seen many questions here that ask about the intuition behind continuity, but I could not find the difference in proving it.

My question now is: Is the following statement true? Apologies for the informal way of writing this.

When working through an exercise and showing that a function is continuous, we take $|f(x)-f(x_{0})|<\varepsilon$ and then we rearrange things until we find $|x-x_{0}|$. From the definition we know that this is $<\delta$ and we start to "estimate" and calculate some things until we get something of the form: $\delta = \varepsilon\ldots$

In the proof, we then plug it in to "hopefully" get rid of everything and only $\varepsilon$ remains.

Is it true that if only $\varepsilon$ remains, the function is uniformly continuous since it does not depend on the $x_{0}$? And that if the $x_{0}$ were to remain, we have that it is continuous, but not uniformly?

Comment: Your intuition is correct, although what you wrote above is not. The problem is that for most functions, you will not be able to compute $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ exactly in a way that allows you to classify when it's smaller than $\varepsilon$ and when it's not. You will, as you stated, only be able to *estimate* the difference. Hence, if you end up with an upper bound, which is dependant on $x_0$, you've *demonstrated* continuity but you haven't *demonstrated* uniform continuity. The function might still very well be uniformly continuous, but your estimation strategy doesn't prove it.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thanks for your comment. I see, so I was wrong about that. How do I then prove uniform continuity? Since my attempt only works for continuity.

Comment: Well, your approach *might* work to prove uniform continuity. But if your approach fails, then that does not prove that your function *isn't* uniformly continuous. Indeed, your approach might also fail to prove continuity (simply because you don't have sufficient control over $f$), but that *also* does not prove that $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: Indeed, to prove that $f$ is discontinuous, you would have to demonstrate some $x_0$ and some $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$, there exists $y$ with $|y-x_0|<\delta$ and $|f(y)-f(x_0)|\geq \varepsilon_0$.
 In the same vein, to prove that $f$ is not uniformly continuous, you would have to demonstrate that there is some $\varepsilon_0>0$ (note the difference in the order in which symbols appear) such that for any $\delta>0$, there exist two points $x,y$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq \varepsilon_0$.

Comment: Note that it is equivalent, and what is most commonly done in practice, to showing that $f$ is discontinuous if there exists $x_0$ and a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n\to x$ but $f(x_n)\not \to f(x)$. Similarly, $f$ is not uniformly continuous if there exists a sequence $\delta_n\to 0$ and an arbitrary sequence $y_n$ such that $f(y_n+\delta_n)-f(y_n)\not\to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to find a $\delta>0$ which depends on $\varepsilon$ but not on $x_0$ then, yes, you shall have proved that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

But what if every $\delta$ that you are able to find depends upon $\varepsilon$ *and* upon $x_0$? Then you shall have proved that $f$ is continuous, but don't jump to the conclusion that it is not uniformly continuous. Take, for instance$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\sqrt x.\end{array}$$If $x_0\in[0,1]$, then$$x-x_0=\left(\sqrt x-\sqrt{x_0}\right)\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x_0}\right)$$and therefore\begin{align}\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|&=\left|\sqrt x-\sqrt{x_0}\right|\\&=\frac{\left|x-x_0\right|}{\sqrt x+\sqrt{x_0}}\\&\leqslant\frac{\left|x-x_0\right|}{\sqrt{x_0}}\end{align}and therefore you can take $\delta=\sqrt{x_0}\,\varepsilon$. But this only works if $x_0\ne0$ and you shall have to find another $\delta$ for the case in which $x_0=0$ ($\delta=\varepsilon^2$ will do then). So, the $\delta$ *does* depend upon $\varepsilon$ *and* upon $x_0$. However, $f$ *is* uniformly continuous (as is every continuous function form an interval $[a,b]$ into $\Bbb R$). The fact that this approach leads to a $\delta$ which depends upon both $\varepsilon$ and $x_0$ doesn't prove that there is no $\delta$ which depends only upon $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks! So basically if I can find such a $\delta$ that depends on $\varepsilon$ but not on $x_{0}$ $\Rightarrow$ Uniform continuity. But  $\delta$ that depends on $\varepsilon$ and $x_{0}$ $\not \Rightarrow$ Not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The fact that you were unable to find a $\delta$ that works does not prove that there is none.